# SQL Pivot Column Explanation

Tags: sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

**Input Data:**

| Occupation | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Doctor | Smith |
| Doctor | George |
| Professor | Baker |
| Singer | Davis |
| Singer | Head |
| Actor | Miller |

**Query:**

```
SELECT [Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor]
FROM (
    SELECT Occupation, Name,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name) AS rn
    FROM OCCUPATIONS
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Name) FOR Occupation IN ([Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor])
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY rn;
```

**Result**

| Doctor | Professor | Singer | Actor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| George | Baker | Davis | Miller |
| Smith | NULL | Head | NULL |

My question is if an aggregate function is being used like max, how am I getting multiple values for occupations?

I tried removing row number and searching if row number was playing any part in this
And I am still not sure

Answer (score 0):

With the `ROW_NUMBER` you can define the order of the result set.

Of course you could achieve this, by changing he order in the row_number window function

```
CREATE TABLE OCCUPATIONS (
  "Occupation" VARCHAR(9),
  "Name" VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO OCCUPATIONS
  ("Occupation", "Name")
VALUES
  ('Doctor', 'Smith'),
  ('Doctor', 'George'),
  ('Professor', 'Baker'),
  ('Singer', 'Davis'),
  ('Singer', 'Head'),
  ('Actor', 'Miller');
```

```
6 rows affected
```

```
SELECT [Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor]
FROM (
    SELECT Occupation, Name,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name) AS rn
    FROM OCCUPATIONS
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Name) FOR Occupation IN ([Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor])
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY rn;
```

| Doctor | Professor | Singer | Actor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| George | Baker | Davis | Miller |
| Smith | *null* | Head | *null* |

```
SELECT [Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor]
FROM (
    SELECT Occupation, Name,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name) AS rn
    FROM OCCUPATIONS
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Name) FOR Occupation IN ([Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor])
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY rn DESC;
```

| Doctor | Professor | Singer | Actor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | *null* | Head | *null* |
| George | Baker | Davis | Miller |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wbhtRAEV)

Comment: My primary question was how am I getting multiple outputs for same values if aggregate function max(Name) is being used?

Comment: Can you add the wanted result, as it is unclear what you mean